# Can't add multiple enviorment paths in osx

Tags: android, macos, grails

I am trying to add multiple environment paths in OSX for Grails and Android.

Here is what my `.bash_profile` looks like

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/Users/jon/Downloads/grails-2.4.0
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
export PATH = ${PATH}:/Users/jon/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH = ${PATH}:/Users/jon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

echo path shows this output:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jon/Downloads/grails-2.4.0/bin
```

Android doesn't seem to get added?

Answer (score 0):

Remove space around the `=` sign and remove `{}` arount the `PATH` variable and change those lines like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/jon/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/jon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```